# Unable to get provider com.microsoft.intune.mam.client.support.v4.content.MAMFileProvider

Tags: android, maui, maui-android, intunemam

When trying to deploy an app using `Microsoft.Intune.Maui.Essentials.android`
we get an exception as below.

> Java.Lang.RuntimeException: 'Unable to get provider
> com.microsoft.intune.mam.client.support.v4.content.MAMFileProvider:
> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
> "com.microsoft.intune.mam.client.support.v4.content.MAMFileProvider"
> on path: DexPathList[[zip file
> "/data/app/~~uJpDSAeopTW92kLUdUgp1w==/jp.co.cegb.archxtractpush-iXeGEc6Slh13UJIq_1k60Q==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~uJpDSAeopTW92kLUdUgp1w==/jp.co.cegb.archxtractpush-iXeGEc6Slh13UJIq_1k60Q==/lib/arm64,
> /data/app/~~uJpDSAeopTW92kLUdUgp1w==/jp.co.cegb.archxtractpush-iXeGEc6Slh13UJIq_1k60Q==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a,
> /system/lib64, /system_ext/lib64]]'

The android manifest is as follows

```
<provider tools:replace="android:authorities" android:name="com.microsoft.intune.mam.client.support.v4.content.MAMFileProvider" android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider" android:exported="false" android:grantUriPermissions="true">
    <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" android:resource="@xml/file_paths" tools:replace="android:resource" />
</provider>
```

Details:

- Microsoft.Intune.Maui.Essentials.android Version: 9.5.2-Beta2
- Operating System (Mac, Linux, Windows) and Version:Windows
- Visual Studio Version: 17.7.4

In Xamarin Android Intune SDK this was not throwing an error.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to change the `com.microsoft.intune.mam.client.support.v4.content.MAMFileProvider` to `androidx.core.content.FileProvider`. Such as:

```
<provider tools:replace="android:authorities" android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider" android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider" android:exported="false" android:grantUriPermissions="true">
    <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" android:resource="@xml/file_paths" tools:replace="android:resource" />
</provider>
```

Comment: My app uses Intune. Is it ok to change it to {androidx.core.content.FileProvider}

I already tried making it. Though this error is gone it says MainActivity did not call through to super.onCreate()

Since is an Intune application we have 

 public class MainActivity : MAMActivity

and we have used public override void OnMAMCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) and not the OnCreate method.

Just thought if this is happening since I have changed com.microsoft.intune.mam.client.support.v4.content.MAMFileProvider to androidx.core.content.FileProvider

Comment: Also I referred to this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/intune/developer/app-sdk-android-appendix  where it asks to Manifest references to android.support.v4.content.FileProvider must be replaced with com.microsoft.intune.mam.client.support.v4.content.MAMFileProvider.

Comment: But the maui used the androidx package instead of the support.v4 package.  Did you try to install the xamarin.android.support.v4 package for the android project? @MichealPatrick

Comment: Im migrating a Xamarin Project to Maui. I have not installed xamarin.android.support.v4 package for the android project in the xamarin also.

Comment: Xamarin Intune sdk has the com.microsoft.intune.mam.client.support.v4.content.MAMFileProvider but the maui doesn't. So you can report an new issue.

Comment: This has been raised as an issue. Waiting for reply. There is no response for past 5 days. https://github.com/msintuneappsdk/ms-intune-app-sdk-android/issues/184